# Quero mostrar em fila numeros. Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

Quero mostrar a saída dos dados em forma de fila, para quantas vezes o usuário quer.

```
def ex1():
    valo = int (input("Insira o numero"))
    for t in range (1,valo+1):
        print((int(valo))*1)
print (ex1())
```

Ex: vezes = 4

```
Saida:
4
44
444
4444
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em python, quando é feito uma `string` `*` 1 número isso indica quantas vezes irá repetir a `string em questão`, sua função pode ser assim:

```
def ex1(): 
    valor = input("Insira o numero: ") 
    repeticoes = int(input("Insira quantas repeticoes deseja: "))
    for item in range(repeticoes + 1):
        print(valor * int(item))
```

Exemplo de saída:

> Insira o numero: 4
>
> Insira quantas repeticoes deseja: 4
>
> 4
> 44
> 444
> 4444

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Serve para números, caracteres e também strings:

```
>>> '4'*2
'44'
>>> '4'*10
'4444444444'
>>> 'a'*10
'aaaaaaaaaa'
>>> 'abc'*3
'abcabcabc'
```

No caso do teu código não é necessário transformá-lo em um inteiro podendo usar o que foi recebido pela função **input()**.